# Conditional expectation of exponential normal random variable

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Suppose the conditional variable is distributed as $X\mid F_t\sim\mathcal{N}(0, \alpha^2)$ and $X\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\beta^2)$.

I want to determine $E[\exp(X)\mid F_t]$. I know that the unconditional expectation is given by $E[\exp(X)]=\exp(\frac{\beta^2}{2})$, now my question is; for the conditional expectation can I simply conclude that $E[\exp(X)\mid F_t]=\exp(\frac{\alpha^2}{2})$?

Intuitively the conditional expectation just provides *additional information* regarding the generating sigma algebra, so my gut instinct says that the conditional expectation is correct. Although I would not be writing this question if if I was convinced, hence could someone provide some help/guidance on this problem.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: What is $F_t$ ? It's a random variable? Why the subscript and what's its relationship with $\alpha$? Do you really mean that $F_t$$ is some random variable but its conditionally expectation does not depend on it?

Comment: The conditional expectation of $e^X$ given $F_t=s$ is the improper integral (via LOTUS) $$E(e^X|F_t=s)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^xf_{X|F_t}(x|s)dx$$ If you're given that $X|F_t=s \sim N(0,\alpha^2)$ for any $s\in \mathbb{R}$ then you will get this expectation to equal $e^{\alpha^2/2}$

Comment: @leonbloy $F_t$ is not important, the only point is that both the conditional and unconditional RV $X$ is normal distributed but with a different variance.

Comment: Your assumption seems impossible to me (unless $\alpha$ depends on $F_t$!). For two rv $X,Y$ , if $f_{X|Y}$ does not depend on $Y$, then $f_{X|Y} = f_X$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\mathbb E\left[e^X \mid F_t\right] &= \int\limits_{x=-\infty}^\infty e^x f(X=x|F_t)dx
\end{align*}
Since $X\mid F_t\sim\mathcal{N}(0, \alpha^2)$, $f(X\mid F_t) = \frac{1}{ \alpha\sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp\left\{-\frac{x^2}{2\alpha^2}\right\}$

Substituting this back,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E\left[e^X \mid F_t\right] &= \int\limits_{x=-\infty}^\infty exp(x) \frac{1}{ \alpha\sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\alpha^2}\right)dx\\
&= \int\limits_{x=-\infty}^\infty  \frac{1}{ \alpha\sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp\left(x-\frac{x^2}{2\alpha^2}\right)dx\\
&= \int\limits_{x=-\infty}^\infty  \frac{1}{ \alpha\sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp\left(\frac{\alpha^4-\alpha^4+2\alpha^2x-x^2}{2\alpha^2}\right)dx\\
&= \int\limits_{x=-\infty}^\infty  \frac{1}{ \alpha\sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp\left(\frac{\alpha^2}{2}-\frac{(x-\alpha^2)^2}{2\alpha^2}\right)dx\\
&= \exp\left(\frac{\alpha^2}{2}\right)\int\limits_{x=-\infty}^\infty  \frac{1}{ \alpha\sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp\left(-\frac{(x-\alpha^2)^2}{2\alpha^2}\right)dx\\
\end{align*}
The term on the right is the pdf of a normal variable with standard deviation $\alpha$ and mean $\alpha^2;\,\sim\mathcal N(\alpha^2,\alpha)$. The integral of any pdf over it's domain (in this case the reals) is 1.

Thus the above expression is
\begin{align}
\mathbb E\left[e^X \mid F_t\right] &= \exp\left(\frac{\alpha^2}{2}\right)\times 1\\ &= \exp\left(\frac{\alpha^2}{2}\right)
\end{align}
which is what you expected

Comment: Very nice answer. I will mark the post as answered. Thank you for taking the time to divert some of your attention :-)